# django mssql password not being acknowledged

Tags: sql, sql-server, django

The official error is "argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable"

Doing some digging I notice that mssql sees 'PASSWORD' as None, even though it is defined in settings (`os.environ.get('DBPW')`)

Doing `os.environ.get('DBPW')` in `python3 manage.py shell` gives me the correct password, and doing `settings.DATABASES['default']` in shell shows the correct password as well, so I know it's some sort of glitch in mssql.

Here are my settings:

```
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'mssql',
            'NAME': 'tc_django_dev',
            'USER': 'SA',
            'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DBPW'),
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': '',

            'OPTIONS': {
                'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
            },
        },
    }
```

Here is what (python) mssql says it has:

`conn_params`:

```
{'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
 'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
 'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
 'ENGINE': 'mssql',
 'HOST': 'localhost',
 'NAME': 'tc_django',
 'OPTIONS': {'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'},
 'PASSWORD': None,
 'PORT': '',
 'TEST': {'CHARSET': None,
          'COLLATION': None,
          'MIGRATE': True,
          'MIRROR': None,
          'NAME': None},
 'TIME_ZONE': None,
 'USER': 'SA'}
```

Help.

Full traceback:

```
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]: Internal Server Error: /accounts/login/
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     response = get_response(request)
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py", line 89, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 138, in dispatch
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 78, in dispatch
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     response = super(RedirectAuthenticatedUserMixin,
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 98, in dispatch
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 94, in get
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     response = super(AjaxCapableProcessFormViewMixin, self).get(
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 133, in get
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 169, in get_context_data
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     site = get_current_site(self.request)
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/sites/shortcuts.py", line 13, in get_current_site
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     return Site.objects.get_current(request)
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/sites/models.py", line 58, in get_current
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     return self._get_site_by_id(site_id)
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/sites/models.py", line 30, in _get_site_by_id
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     site = self.get(pk=site_id)
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 425, in get
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     num = len(clone)
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 269, in __len__
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     self._fetch_all()
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1303, in _fetch_all
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in __iter__
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1143, in execute_sql
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     sql, params = self.as_sql()
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mssql/compiler.py", line 188, in as_sql
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     supports_offset_clause = self.connection.sql_server_version >= 2012
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mssql/base.py", line 414, in sql_server_version
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     with self.temporary_connection() as cursor:
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     return next(self.gen)
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 603, in temporary_connection
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     with self.cursor() as cursor:
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     return func(*args, **kwargs)
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 259, in cursor
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     return self._cursor()
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mssql/base.py", line 230, in _cursor
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     conn = super()._cursor()
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 235, in _cursor
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     self.ensure_connection()
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     return func(*args, **kwargs)
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     self.connect()
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     return func(*args, **kwargs)
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mssql/base.py", line 307, in get_new_connection
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     connstr = encode_connection_string(cstr_parts)
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mssql/base.py", line 52, in encode_connection_string
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     return ';'.join(
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mssql/base.py", line 53, in <genexpr>
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     '%s=%s' % (k, encode_value(v))
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:   File "/home/webadmin/dev.taracares.com/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mssql/base.py", line 62, in encode_value
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]:     if ';' in v or v.strip(' ').startswith('{'):
Aug 22 09:39:53 tclnx01 gunicorn[2634]: TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Comment: Do you store it in a .env file or just do a export?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try os.environ['DBPW'] instead of .get method?